# INNER JOIN Taking longer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am joining a sub query with a table.

Sub query runs for 5 Seconds (returns 20 records) and the table has only 4 rows.

Sub query:

```
Select ID, Name, JoinID
FROM tableX
JOIN ..
```

Sub query Sample Result:

```
1, xx, 1
2, yy, 2
3, zz, 1
4, vv, 2
5, bb, 1
```

TableY (ID, Description):
Data

```
1, test1
2, test2
3, test3
4, test4
```

My below query is taking more than 30 seconds. What am I doing wrong here? I see no issue with table Stats. Also sub query is not returning any NULL record for JoinID column.

```
Select sub.*, tab.*
from
(
sub query
) sub
Join tableY on tableY.ID = sub.JoinID
```

Comment: Question related to query performance should include execution plans etc.

Comment: Is there any indexes in your tables

Answer (score 0):

Joining subqueries would be slow in some cases. If your tables has not PK or FK indexes joining would be complex for database engines.

First check your tables. Add primary keys to ID columns if you dont have. Create foreign key on JOINID in TABLEX. If you already done and same result then you must create index on JOINID if this not works also then you must check your server configuration, check database engine documentation (Oracle,Mssql,mysql etc.)

You can use this SQL statement to get same result without using subquery,

```
SELECT X.*, Y.*
FROM TABLEX as X 
JOIN TABLEX as Y ON (X.JOIN_ID=Y.ID)
```

Use subqueries if you have aggregate functions or multiple joins in subquery sql statement.

Comment: The tables are different. have edited the table name.

Comment: Ok i can see that you have one table in your subquery. We are not using subqueries like that. I edited my answer, please check and try, let me know if it works